# Is there any way to change the color of the dates using UICalendarView?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uicalendarview

I'm currently using UICalendarView for a calendar in my app, however I can't seem to find a way to change the colour of the dates or any other parts of the calendar. I know you can change the tintcolor, but there doesn't seem to be any option to change the main colour of the dates.

```
struct CalendarView: UIViewRepresentable {
   
    let interval: DateInterval
    @ObservedObject var eventStore: EventStore
    @Binding var dateSelected: DateComponents?
    @Binding var displayEvents: Bool
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UICalendarView {
        
        
        let view = UICalendarView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        view.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        view.availableDateRange = interval
        let dateSelection = UICalendarSelectionSingleDate(delegate: context.coordinator)
        view.selectionBehavior = dateSelection
        view.fontDesign = .rounded
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        view.layer.cornerCurve = .continuous
        view.tintColor = UIColor.red
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 12
```

This is a part of my code, and my backgroundColor is set to clear because behind the calendar is a dark coloured image. However I want the colour of all the dates to be white so that it is visible behind the dark background, but they are going to black by default and I can't seem to find a way to change that.

Comment: The `calendarView(_:decorationFor:)` method of `UICalendarViewDelegate` might be what you're looking for if you need more customisation of the calendar view. See the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicalendarviewdelegate/3972051-calendarview).

Comment: "colour of the dates" -> which elements? I assume you don't simply mean the event's text, background and (bold) left border... these appear to be derived from the calendar's color prop.